# QTcpSocket status is incorrect

Tags: qt, sockets, status, qtcpsocket

I am using Qt 4.8.2 (64 bit) on Linux Debian.

I am having problem with socket status. I am client connecting to server, my relevant code snippet is:

```
QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
socket->connectToHost(interface[cameras[listnum].interface].ip,interface[cameras[listnum].interface].port);
qDebug() << socket->waitForConnected(10000);
qDebug() << socket->isValid();
qDebug() << socket->state();
```

I am connecting to server that is local to me and I can disconnect Ethernet cable to it to test both connected and non-connected states. I can tell if I connect by the wait time, if cable is connected to server then waitForConnected takes less than 0.5 seconds and if cable is not connected then waitForConnected times out at 10 seconds.

My problem is I get the same status connected or not. The output of the qDebug is:

false

true

QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState

And it stays this way if I am really connected or not. When connected I can send data. I also put the last two statements in command button and verified the return status does not change even after several seconds or minutes.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no point to checking if a socket is valid, it's the state you're interested in.

If, as you've shown, the `waitForConnected` returns false, then you can be sure that the `state` is also unconnected - no point in further checking it.

When the connection succeeds, `waitForConnected` should return true, and `state` should return the connected state. It may be that the `state` will only turn true after you've drained the remaining events, although it would be a Qt 4.8.2 quirk (can't you try on 4.8.5 or 5.3.1?).

I'm somehow skeptical that what you describe really happens, but if it does, you'll need to convince us first. Write a self contained test case (a single `main.cpp` file), edit it into your question, verify that it does still happen on Qt 4.8.5, and then submit a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The qDebug is only for current diagnostics and will not be in final code, they show the incorrect state.  In another section of code I send data though this socket and state() still returns UnconnectedState.  I have to finish my current project and then I will do what you suggest to prove bug.  I have done work around by timing response of waitForConnected and then set my own flag as to connection state, it works.  Thanks again.

Comment: Try it at least using Qt 4.8.5.

Comment: @Kuba ober .. does this answer from windless1015 make sense?

Comment: I don’t use synchronous APIs so I truly don’t know if such a hack “makes sense”. To me, the whole point of using Qt is that it’s open source and you can easily build it, debug it and modify it. It’s much easier than dealing with hacks and workarounds. Out of all the monstrous open source projects, building Qt is among the simplest, for what it’s worth. No reason to avoid that, I don’t think.